# Only Specify Certain Parameters in Command Objects in ADO with VBScript?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ado

If I have a stored procedure in SQL Server with a number of named input parameters, all with default values as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_name] 
(   
    @IN_mode CHAR(1) = NULL, /* 'I','U'*/
    @IN_external_identity_id INT = -1,
    @IN_provider_name VARCHAR(45) = NULL,
    @IN_login_id VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @IN_email VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @IN_ip VARCHAR(45) = NULL,
    @IN_first_name VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @IN_last_name VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @IN_json_response_raw VARCHAR(8000) = NULL,
    @IN_user_id VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @IN_name VARCHAR(255) = NULL
)
AS 
    BEGIN
...
```

...and in the `vbScript` I call the procedure like this:

```
Set oSproc = CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
With oSproc
    .ActiveConnection = oConn
    .CommandText = "bfsp_insert_NEW_EXTERNAL_IDENTITY"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
    With .Parameters
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_mode", adChar, adParamInput, 1, "I")
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_external_identity_id", adInteger, adParamInput, 0, -1) '-1 because field isn't needed on new insert
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_provider_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 45, "FACEBOOK")
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_login_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, getInput("fbNewUserName"))
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_email", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.email)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_ip", adVarChar, adParamInput, 46, getUserIp())
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_first_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.first_name)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_last_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.last_name)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_json_response_raw", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8000, oFbUser.rawJson)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_user_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.id)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.name)
    End With 
    .Execute 
End With 
iNewExternalIdentityId = oSproc.parameters("@OUTPUT_originalId").Value 'grabbing the new EXTERNAL_IDENTITY.ID 
Set oSproc = Nothing
```

I noticed that the parameter name in the vbscript create parameter statement doesn't link by name to the variable in the sproc. It seems to be matching up based on ordinal position e.g. param 1 matches param 1, and so on.  If I left one out, say, in the middle somewhere, all remaining parameters will be assigned to the wrong input variable in the sproc.

How can I create parameters in vbscript code so that I can send in only the select parameters I need, and still have them match up correctly with the parameters in the procedure?

Comment: Try `.NamedParameters = True`, per https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms675840 (disclaimer: not tested).

Comment: Otherwise, another alternative would be to add the parameter(s) with no values (or null) instead of omitting a parameter.

Comment: @jeroen-mostert - that worked... I'll create a formal answer with your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting a formal answer incorporating the suggestion from @jeroen-mostert.

All that is needed to pass parameters by name is to add the `namedParameters` property to the command object and set it to `True` as follows. Line 3 in the snippet below was added, otherwise it is the same as the original:

```
Set oSproc = CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
With oSproc
    .NamedParameters = True
    .ActiveConnection = oConn
    .CommandText = "bfsp_insert_NEW_EXTERNAL_IDENTITY"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
    With .Parameters
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_mode", adChar, adParamInput, 1, "I")
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_external_identity_id", adInteger, adParamInput, 0, -1) '-1 because field isn't needed on new insert
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_provider_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 45, "FACEBOOK")
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_login_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, getInput("fbNewUserName"))
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_email", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.email)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_ip", adVarChar, adParamInput, 46, getUserIp())
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_first_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.first_name)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_last_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.last_name)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_json_response_raw", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8000, oFbUser.rawJson)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_user_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.id)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, oFbUser.name)
    End With 
    .Execute 
End With 
iNewExternalIdentityId = oSproc.parameters("@OUTPUT_originalId").Value 'grabbing the new EXTERNAL_IDENTITY.ID 
Set oSproc = Nothing
```